# render json as output in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a method in my rails controller and in the controller I need to render the output as a message in json format.

```
def createItem
    @item = Item.new(params[:item])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.json { render json: message: "Item is successfully Created" }
      else
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

But when I submit the form, the browser is  displaying blank. I need to render the json text as above. How do I do it. Please help

Answer (score 2):

You could change,

```
def createItem
  @item = Item.new(params[:item])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @item.save
      format.json { render json: message: "Item is successfully Created" }
    else
      format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

To

```
def createItem
  @item = Item.new(params[:item])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @item.save
      json_string = {'message' => 'Item is successfully Created'}.to_json
      format.json { render :json => {item: @item, json_string}
    else
      format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the JSON request you should have to give the `.json` at the end of your URL.

Suppose that you dont want to give the url, in your model you should type :

```
def as_json(options={})
    { :name => self.name }  # NOT including the email field
end

def as_json(options={})
    super(:only => [:name])
end
```

And then in your controller :

```
def index 
  @names = render :json => Name.all 
end
```

Then the JSON code will automatically come to picture without using `.json`.